# Image texture (UV Map) blend with procedural rough material

Tags: uv

is it possible the image texture blend with procedural rough material? Any tips/suggestion to achieve like this one:

[image]

My attempt:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Your attempt looks fine to me. How do you want to change it?

Comment: I want the white label will look like it was printed or overlay on the rough surface. If you look closely in the first image. The logo looks like it was overlay with the rough surface.

Comment: You would need to apply the normal map to the logo as well by plugging it into the Diffuse node.

Comment: Thanks **rjg** for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I got the solution without bake normal maps. I'm happy of the result (sort of). Thanks **rjg** for the hint.

Before

[image]

After

[image]